# What is the equivalent of Python's "findAll" function in PHP?

Tags: php, findall

```
re.findall(r'(\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(?=\.com\b)', DATA)
```

how would this line be in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`preg_match_all`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Comment: no, preg_match_all returns the number of matches, not the strings that match themselves

Comment: Who said it didn't? It still gives you the matches via the $matches array reference.

Comment: GSto, please read the link posted by Josh. As already mentioned: you're wrong. preg_match_all can be used just fine.

Comment: Just a heads up: Python's `re.findall` and PHP's `preg_match_all` give different results if your pattern contains capturing groups. `preg_match_all` will give an array of arrays, each one containing the whole expression and the captured groups, while python function will return an array of captured groups directly.

Answer (score 4):

`preg_match_all('/(\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(?=.com\b)/',$data,$matches);`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out http://php.net/preg_match_all

Comment: no, preg_match_all returns the number of matches, not the strings that match themselves

Comment: That's wholly incorrect, sir. As seen in Felipe's response, the 3rd parameter to preg_match_all is the matches themselves.